# Joomla Error: "shell command execution from POST/GET variables"

Tags: php, joomla, malware

I have a hacked Joomla site and ran a program called jamss which identifies possible security threats. One of the recommendations says:

> Pattern #23 - shell command execution from POST/GET variables -->
>   found 1 occurence(s) in file ./xxx/xxx/index.php
>
> Details: "Found direct shell command execution getting variables from
>   POST/GET, which is highly dangerous security flaw or a part of
>   malicious webrootkit"
>
> Line #: 12

But I don't understand what that means. The code is referring to this line:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');        <----------------------
$url = clone(JURI::getInstance());
$path = $this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template;
$rel_path = $this->baseurl.'/images/stories/';
```

And I don't see any POST or GET variables there. Does anyone know why this line of code would be considered a security flaw?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JAMSS](https://github.com/btoplak/Joomla-Anti-Malware-Scan-Script/blob/master/jamss.php) rule #23 checks for these php functions:

exec|passthru|shell_exec|system|proc_|popen

if any is present in the script, the alert [23] will be triggered.
Possibly JAMSS doesn't report the correct line or filename, but simply run a

```
grep -rE "(?:exec|passthru|shell_exec|system|proc_|popen)[\w\W\s/\*]*\([\s/\*\#\'\"\w\W\-\_]*" .
```

on the command line and you should see the actual files and the line numbers.  Careful: you'll also get some extra false positives.